# How to apply css styles to a tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a tag in my html inside `<i>`. I am already applying some styles to all `<a>` tags in my HTML. But i would like to separate any `<a>` tag which is in an `<i>` tag. How can I do it?

```
a.aCategory:link {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a.aCategory:visited {
    color: #999999;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a.aCategory:active {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a.aCategory:hover {
    color: #999999;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a.aSubCategory:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a.aSubCategory:visited {
    color: #999999;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a.aSubCategory:active {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a.aSubCategory:hover {
    color: #999999;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a:link {
    color: #3B73B9;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    color: #3B73B9;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
    color: #3B73B9;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #064D6E;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I do not want to apply the above styles to <a> tag which is inside <i> tag in my html

Comment: I wrote seperate class for <a> tag 

.mylnk {
 font-family: italic;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #FF00FF;
    
}

But i am unable to change the color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is to add different style to a tag inside i just use 'i a' for all descendant or 'i > a' for direct child a of i.

Second thing is you should write this style after style you have written for all a tag.

```
a.aCategory:link {
   color: #000000;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
i a.aCategory:link{
   //enter your style here
}
a.aCategory:visited {
   color: #999999;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
i a.aCategory:visited{
   //enter your style here
}
a.aCategory:active {
   color: #000000;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
i a.aCategory:active{
   //enter your style here
}
a.aCategory:hover {
   color: #999999;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
i a.aCategory:hover{
   //enter your style here
}
a.aSubCategory:link {
   color: #000000;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
i a.aSubCategory:link{
   //enter your style here
}
a.aSubCategory:visited {
   color: #000000;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
i a.aSubCategory:visited{
   //enter your style here
}
a.aSubCategory:active {
   color: #000000;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
i a.aSubCategory:active{
   //enter your style here
}
a.aSubCategory:hover {
   color: #000000;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
i a.aSubCategory:hover{
   //enter your style here
}
a:link {
   color: #000000;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
i a:link{
   //enter your style here
}
a:visited {
   color: #000000;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
i a:visited{
   //enter your style here
}
a:active {
   color: #000000;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
i a:active{
   //enter your style here
}
a:hover {
   color: #000000;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
i a:hover{
   //enter your style here
}
```

NOTE : in above code if you want to apply different style for only child a tag if i tag then use i > a instead.

Comment: There is no HTML code provided in the question and no attempt at setting anything related to `i` elements. The question title does not help at all in trying to guess what the question is about.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unnormal css selector:

```
a[href="http://example.com"] {
  color: #1f6053;
}
```

for exepted links.

Also can use `:not` :

```
a:not(#example) {
   color: blue;
}
```

And insert to target element `id="example"`

Also:

```
i > a {
   color: red;
}
```

selected the target `<a>`

Comment: i a {
 
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background-color: #3B73B9;
    
}

I tried this.I am able to apply all stles instead of color

Comment: In CSS for overwrite style use `color:#3B5998  !important;`

Answer (score 0):

You can apply specific styles to children of a tag using CSS child selectors.

For example, in your case:

```
i > a { /* your styles */ } /* will select immediate child */
i a { /* your styles */ } /* will select all nested children */
```

However, if you are over-writing a lot of rules using these selectors for "a" tags then it might be a good idea to re-think your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use CSS3 selectors Use the [:not](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) pseudo class prefixed to your `a` tag styles

```
*:not(i) > a { }
*:not(i) > a.aSubCategory { }
...
```

This will make it so all `a` tags not in `i` tags are given the styles, while those that are do not get them.

Otherwise you would have to reset/override the styles

```
i a:linked {
    color: initial;
    font-family: initial;
    font-size: initial;
    font-weight: initial;   
}
...
```

Comment: I am unable to change the color